# NHibernate new session with transaction in existing transaction

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

can this code makes some bad things? I found it in one project and do not know if it can be cause of some crazy bugs(deadlocks, timeouts in DB,...). Code like this is executed concurently many times in program even in threads.

Thanks a lot

```
class first {
    void doSomething { 
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction){

            var foo = new second();
            foo.doInNewTransaction(); //inner transaction in new session

            transaction.Commit();
          } 
    }
}

class second {
    void doInNewTransaction(){
        using (Session session = new Session()){
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction){

                //do someting in database   
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't doing 'bad' things at the moment, however you can add code which does. You can't prevent 'bad things' with code constructs, only with develpers who know what they are doing.

Comment: of course, I need to know if this practice is bad in general - I mean...opening new session and transaction within existing transaction

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine. I'm sure I have done stuff like this in the past. The only thing that you need to be aware of is that if you modify an object in the inner session then these changes will not automatically be reflected in the outer session if the same object has already been loaded.

Having said that, if you do not need to do this then I would avoid it. Normally I would recommend AOP based transaction management when using NHibernate. This would allow your inner component to easily join in with the transaction from the outer component. However, in order to do this you need to be using a DI container that supports this, for example Spring.NET or Castle.